# Can we ban affiliate links?

Tags: feature-request

I just got a not very useful answer to a question with an Amazon affiliate link to a relevant but very easily found product. That is, the answer would have been just as useful without the link. The link was shortened (amzn.to/…), and when put through `curl --max-redirs 0` the redirect clearly contained a `tag`, [as far as I know](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/104291/8469) making it an affiliate link. Can we ban any such links, to make sure the SO incentive structure is maintained? Ideally such a ban would be in the form of a helpful hint to the user that they have to use the unshortened, non-affiliate version of the link to be allowed to link to products.

Answer (score 9):

Based on [this Meta SE answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/2727/284141), all affiliate links should be flagged as spam. If you do see one, please flag it and the moderator team will take care of it.